# QR Code Generator

Tags: php, qr-code

ive been reading up on QR Codes a lot recently, I want to code my own generator with PHP. But i'm having trouble, as they are rather complicated, does anyone know of any tutorials for this sort of thing?

I found this, but I get stuck when trying to convert the result from page 3 to a 11-bit binary result. I'm also confused as to why "H" ASCII value is 17 on that table, but it is 72 on the ASCII table below...

[image]

The main issue i'm having is generating it, I was thinking about using a table for the pixels. I want to eventually be able to generate my own QR Code like the one below, but different text in the middle and different content:
[image: I want this!]

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "page 3"?

Comment: Referring to the number he makes from "HE", which is 779.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you do NOT use tables for generating QR codes.  This is way too much overhead for the browser, and if a browser renderes the box model that is off by 1 pixel, your whole image will be crap.

I would take a look at generating your images on the sever in php using GD2.

http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFVcOFmnZ9Y

If you really want to generate images inside the browser, you could probably get away with a HTML canvas tag.

If you want to add text I suggest you layer the text on-top using GD2.  If you are using an SVG library I'm not exactly sure how to layer, but it should be simple.  Here's an example of layering in GD2:

http://phpimageworkshop.com/

The thing to realize about QR codes is that they can store up to 30% redundant data.  That means that you can "destroy" 30% of the code by layering an image on-top and it will still work.  Here are some guides about customizing QR codes with logos etc:

http://blog.qr4.nl/post/QR-Code-Error-Recovery.aspx

http://mashable.com/2011/04/18/qr-code-design-tips/

Comment: I would strongly suggest using SVG as your output. I've had very good luck with it and it's quite easy to do.

Comment: @portforwardpodcast how do i add the text through the middle?

Answer (score 1):

There are many php classes and external libraries available to generate QR code using php. I have listed some of them below. You can refer these links.

- http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/‎
- http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6399-PHP-Generate-QR-Code-images-using-Google-Chart-API.html
- http://qrcodescript.com/